# How to change operating system detected by headless Chrome?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, headless, pyppeteer

I use pyppeteer. But when I go to https://ipleak.net it detects my real OS.
I try to load this scrypt with

```py
async with aiofiles.open(os.path.join(BASEDIR, 'preload.js'), mode='r') as f:
    preloadFile  = await f.read()

# code for opening browser and page
# .......

await page.evaluateOnNewDocument(preloadFile)
```

*preload.js*

```js
var fakePlatformGetter = function () {
  return "Linux armv8l";
};
if (Object.defineProperty) {
  Object.defineProperty(navigator, "platform", {
    get: fakePlatformGetter
  });
} else if (Object.prototype.__defineGetter__) {
  navigator.__defineGetter__("platform", fakePlatformGetter);
}
```

but it doesn't work.
What can I do to hide my real operating system?

Answer (score 0):

```py
client = await page.target.createCDPSession()
client.send('Network.setUserAgentOverride', {'userAgent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 10; MI 9) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.96 Mobile Safari/537.36', 'platform': 'Linux armv8l'})
```